# Как из списка словарей извлечь один из словарей

Tags: python, словари, список

К примеру у нас есть список состоящий из трех словарей:

```
[
  {'one':1,'two':2},
  {'home':'Дом','Cat':'Кошка'},
  {'red':'красный','green':'Зеленый'}
]
```

Как из этого списка извлечь первый словарь и записать его в другую переменную, чтобы тип переменной был `dict`?

Comment: чтобы с новой переменной ,можно было работать как с словарем

Comment: Не важно, что в списке: числа, словари, другие какие-то объекты. Обычным образом обращаетесь к элементам списка по индексу и берёте нужный элемент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_dicts =  [{'one':1,'two':2},{'home':'Дом','Cat':'Кошка'},{'red':'красный','green':'Зеленый'}]
first_dict = list_dicts[0]
```

В чем проблема-то?

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @io2232, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: если Вам помогло, поставьте галочку напротив ответа

Comment: а как это сделать через цикл? у меня есть список из словарей с одинаковыми ключами, как через цикл вытащить все нужные пары и записать в другой список?

Comment: Создайте для этого отдельный вопрос с примером кода